# US Citizen Wanting To Retire in UK

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit

I am a US Citizen, but I would love to retire abroad - UK.  Even though I have never worked there, how might I be able to settle there?  I would be living on multiple pensions earned in the US and a defined contribution annuity (401K), so I would not need public assistance.

Comment: long shot: check your personal (and/or spousal) ancestry/immigration history to see if you qualify for citizenship to any EU country.  i believe that holding the passport of any EU country would allow you to reside in the UK indefinitely as a pensioner, so long as you can prove you won't take any social services.  source: have italian passport, never been to italy

Comment: You should really ask why you want to do this. That would answer a few of the 'how' questions right there.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at the different visas offered by the [UKBA](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/work-visas). The [Tier 1 Investor](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-investor) is often the only route for self/unemployed US citizens to settle in the UK. It requires £2 million to be invested in the UK.

Comment: Tiny nitpick.  UKBA was abolished in 2013.  Your answer is still fine though.

Comment: @GayotFow so are they now UKVI?

Comment: Yes, they are now wearing UKVI hats

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have £2m for a UK Investor visa you could try a cheaper "golden visa" country first (for example, Malta, Portugal or Greece), with the aim of obtaining an EU citizenship that way.

Comment: With the way things look politically, I am not sure I would make a long term bet on Greece.